# html2canvas works flawlessly on desktop but in one of the cases doesn't work on phone

Tags: javascript, html, css, html2canvas

On my page I am screenshooting two parts of the webpage which is triggered by button press. On desktop both of them works just fine. On phone one is working also okay but the other one is not. Here is code used to trigger second:

```
    html2canvas(document.getElementById("emotion-result-table")).then(canvas => {
      this.imageTable = canvas.toDataURL("image/png")
    });
```

And I chcecked `then` is never called but also doesn't throw any errors. Here is some of the code which I am trying to screenshot:

```
<div id="emotion-result-table" sex="male" data-v-64636664="" data-v-4815f62e="">
<div data-v-64636664="">
  <div className="flex frame justify-around items-center" data-v-64636664="">
    <div className="flex justify-center relative-position" data-v-64636664="">
      <div className="user-image" data-v-64636664=""
           style="background-image: url(&quot;data:image/png;base64,&quot;); background-size: cover; background-position: center top;"></div>
      <img src="/img/happy.b68bbc93.svg" className="emotion-image absolute" alt="Emotion image" data-v-64636664="">
    </div>
    <div className="flex justify-center relative-position" data-v-64636664="">
      <div className="user-image" data-v-64636664=""
           style="background-image: url(&quot;data:image/png;base64,&quot;); background-size: cover; background-position: center top;"></div>
      <img src="/img/sad.d1999e7e.svg" className="emotion-image absolute" alt="Emotion image" data-v-64636664=""></div>
    <div className="flex justify-center relative-position" data-v-64636664="">
      <div className="user-image" data-v-64636664=""
           style="background-image: url(&quot;data:image/png;base64,&quot;); background-size: cover; background-position: center top;"></div>
      <img src="/img/angry.69f25221.svg" className="emotion-image absolute" alt="Emotion image" data-v-64636664="">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div data-v-64636664="">
  <div className="flex frame justify-around items-center" data-v-64636664="">
    <div className="flex justify-center relative-position" data-v-64636664="">
      <div className="user-image" data-v-64636664=""
           style="background-image: url(&quot;data:image/png;base64,&quot;); background-size: cover; background-position: center top;"></div>
      <img src="/img/fearful.5636905b.svg" className="emotion-image absolute" alt="Emotion image" data-v-64636664="">
    </div>
    <div className="flex justify-center relative-position" data-v-64636664="">
      <div className="user-image" data-v-64636664=""
           style="background-image: url(&quot;data:image/png;base64,&quot;); background-size: cover; background-position: center top;"></div>
      <img src="/img/disgusted.3fe55874.svg" className="emotion-image absolute" alt="Emotion image" data-v-64636664="">
    </div>
    <div className="flex justify-center relative-position" data-v-64636664="">
      <div className="user-image" data-v-64636664=""
           style="background-image: url(&quot;data:image/png;base64,CC&quot;); background-size: cover; background-position: center top;"></div>
      <img src="/img/surprised.d06d4934.svg" className="emotion-image absolute" alt="Emotion image" data-v-64636664="">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Of course i deleted the string with image so it becomes more readable.

Not sure if relevant but I also find out that on the phone in the console I get error: `Maxium call stack size exceeded` which is not present on the desktop

Comment: "maximum call stack size exceeded" means you have a recursive function somewhere in your code. That means the code is continuosly called.

What is the OS on both phones and on desktop? Could be a browser specific issue.

Comment: Could you show us the actual code that you are trying to screenshot? The HTML in the question looks as though it is waiting for stuff to be filled in/altered so I guess some JS is run on it before the call to html2canvas.

Comment: Like I said I deleted the part where is image data written in string. Beside this it's filled in. And i found answer to my question, and i wrote it in answer

Answer (score 0):

Okay I found a solution here is github issue:

https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/issues/1858

TLDR:
I was using background-image in css which works fine on the desktop. But html2canas still doesn't support this on the phone.

So in order to do it properly you have to put your background as  instead of using background-image

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).